# Ruby on rails - Create multiple records from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, database, activerecord

I have a form for my model `@gig`. I am trying to create multiple `gigs` at once with the same attributes apart from `date` which should be picked from an array.

So far only the last date in the array and only one record is getting saved.

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= simple_form_for @gig , url: gigs_path do |form| %>
         <div class="create-title">
            <%= form.input :title, label: t('gig.title'), placeholder: t('placeholder.title') %>
         </div>

          bla... bla... bla....

         <p><%= t('gig.date') %> </p>
           <% if !mobile_device? %>
             <%= form.input :date, as: :string, label: false, placeholder: t('placeholder.date'), multiple: true %>
           <% else %>

                       bla... bla... bla....
    <% end %>
```

gig_controler.rb

```
    def create
      @gigdates = params[:gig][:date].split(';')
      puts @gigdates.count
        @gigdates.each do |date|
            puts date
           @gig = Gig.create(gig_params)
           @gig.date = date
         end

        if @gig.save

          redirect_to @gig
        else
          Rails.logger.info(@gig.errors.inspect)
          render 'new'
        end
      end




     def gig_params
       params.require(:gig).permit(:title, :location, :description, :date, :salary, :salary_cents, :salary_currency, :genre_ids => [])
     end
```

Using `puts date` in the controller, I can see that my dates are getting separated correctly.

The server shows `ROLLBACK` is called as many times as there are dates in the array and then the final `gig` saves correctly.

---

Update 1:

I have changed the controller which allows the creation of multiple records, I am just worried about the lack of redirects or messages if a record fails to save.

```
def create

  @gigdates = params[:gig][:date].split(';')
    @gigdates.each do |date|
       @gig = Gig.new(gig_params)
       @gig.date = date
       @genres = Genre.where(:id => params[:choose_genres])
       @gig.genres << @genres
       @gig.save
     end

    redirect_to @gig
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

For each date in the `@gig_dates` array you are creating an invalid gig with `gig_params`. It's invalid because the `date` key of `gig_params` will be the string originally entered in the form, e.g. `"2017-01-3;2017-05-09;2017-08-01"`. This is an invalid date, hence all the `ROLLBACK`s – your calls to `Gig.create` are all failing at the database level.

Let's take a deeper look at what is happening:

```
  # EACH LOOP BEGINS
  # for each gig date:
  @gigdates.each do |date|
    # gig_params[:date] will be the whole string that was entered in the
    # form. this is an invalid date, so Gig.create will fail to save the
    # gig to the database (= ROLLBACK). 
    # so you create an gig, but it can't be saved because its date parameter
    # is invalid. you assign this invalid gig to the @gig instance
    # variable. this variable will be overwritten each time, so only the
    # last created gig is stored in @gig
    @gig = Gig.create(gig_params)

    # you assign that invalid gig a (valid) date (but you don't save it!)
    @gig.date = date
  end
  # EACH LOOP ENDS

  # Save @gig, the last created gig, using the valid date you assigned 
  # it at the end of the each loop. so now the save will work!
  if @gig.save
    redirect_to @gig
  else
    Rails.logger.info(@gig.errors.inspect)
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Edit:

One way to deal with validation would be to check the validity of all the new gigs before saving any of them. To do this you can replace your `each` with a map, which will create an array of your new gigs, and then check if all of them are valid before saving them all:

```
def create
  gigdates = params[:gig][:date].split(';')

  gigs = gigdates.map do |date|
    gig = Gig.new(gig_params.merge(date: date))
    genres = Genre.where(:id => params[:choose_genres])
    gig.genres << genres
  end

  if gigs.all?(&:valid?) && gigs.all?(&:save)
    redirect_to gigs.first
  else
    flash[:notice] = "something went wrong"
    @gig = Gig.new(gig_params)
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I have updated my question with an updated version. I can now save the multiple records but there is no validation or flash messages on fail.

Comment: @RobHughes see my edit for a fairly naive example of how to deal with validation. It's not ideal (for example there would be inconsistencies if all the gigs were valid but some of them still couldn't be saved for whatever reason). One better way of dealing with this problem would be to simplify the create action to only make one gig at a time and have the browser make an individual request for each gig (e.g. using a bit of javascript to send ajax requests). But that's rather out of the scope of this question.